# Check if date is certain month

Tags: php, date

I have two dates, one from an API which I can't change. And one I create myself which is a month. I want to check if the date i get from the api is in the same month i provide.

Example:

```
$month = '12'; //december
$date = '2019-12-09 13:34:23' // date from api (cant change the way it comes in)
```

In this case the date is in the month december (like my variable) so i would like to  built something that returns true if this is the case, but sadly i dont know where to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$dateValue = strtotime($q);                     

$yr = date("Y", $dateValue); 
$mon = date("m", $dateValue); 
$date = date("d", $dateValue);
```

you can do something like this then 
you can match with if condition.

Comment: why are you concatenating with " "?

Comment: you can ignore  concatenation

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this perhaps:

```
$month = '12';
$date = '2019-12-09 13:34:23';

if( date('M',strtotime($date)) == date('M', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1, date('Y') ) ) )echo 'same';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [date_parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_parse.asp) :

```
$date = date_parse($date);
if ($month == $date['month']) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With explode:

```
if( explode('-',$date)[1] == $month ) {
  echo 'check ok';
}
```

With DateTime

```
if( date_create($date)->format('m') == $month ) {
  echo 'check ok';
}
```